# gitlab-ci не корректно работает сборка

Tags: java, gitlab, devops, kubernetes, gitlab-ci

Всем привет. Есть проблема при работе gitlab-ci. Сборка java через mvn и упаковка собранного Jar файла в докер.
В варианте build package dockerise не собирается jar файл. По логам он есть, но если смотреть по пути где он якобы собрался, файл отсутствует.
Но если убрать стадию dockerise то всё прекрасно отрабатывает и jar файл собирается. Такое ощущение что стадия dockerise как-то затирает верхние стадии сборки.
Так же, если все команды, mvn package, docker build, docker push оставить в одной стадии, в пределах script, всё собирается как нужно.
Не  могу понять в чем проблема. Кто подскажет?
Вот сам код CI

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
  APP_NAME: app-api
  
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

stages:
  - build
  - package
  - dockerise

Build Project:
  stage: build
  tags: [dev]
  only:
    - release
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS compile

Package artifacts:
  stage: package
  image: openjdk:17-alpine
  tags: [dev]
  only:
    - release
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar

Dockerise:
  stage: dockerise
  image: docker:latest
  tags: [dev]
  only:
    - release
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - cd app
    - docker build -t $CI_OPENSHIFT_REGISTRY/dev/$APP_NAME:latest .
    - docker login "$CI_OPENSHIFT_REGISTRY" -p $(oc whoami -t) -u "$OPENSHIFT_USER"
    - docker push  $CI_OPENSHIFT_REGISTRY/dev/$APP_NAME:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Артефакты не передаются просто так от стадии к стадии.

Чтобы передать артефакт одна стадия должна объявить `artifacts` (у тебя сделано), а другая объявить зависимость (`dependencies`) от этой стадии (у тебя не сделано).

```
Dockerise:
  dependencies: 
    - Package artifacts
  ...
```